Unknown issue with Adafruit AOI on Python
I was trying to make an automation for turning my PC on using IFTTT + Google Assistant, and Adafruit. I Wrote the script, but here comes a problem. This script works fine when I don't need it, but when I really need to turn my PC on(usually mornings), my script just refuses to receive messages from Adafruit.
I know that my aplet on IFTTT is running, because I was receiving notifications. And the program is running. I set a loop that sleeps for 10 minutes, then gives data to Ada's broker and print the value and time when the value was given to broker, and I always see that my script is working fine but doesn't receive messages.
Here's the code:
import sys



import time



from datetime import datetime



import socket



import subprocess



import random



from Adafruit_IO import MQTTClient







ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = "mavr"



ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = "aio_HELc19FRVNxzbtw1E9Ej5Bwu5epD"



IO_FEED = 'pc'











# MQTT callback functions







def connected(client):



    client.subscribe(IO_FEED, ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME)







def disconnected(client):



    print('Disconnected from Adafruit IO! Goodbye!')



    sys.exit(1)







def message(client, feed_id, payload):                              # this will be called when a subscribed feed has a new value



    print(f'Feed {feed_id} received new value: {payload}')



    if payload == 'ON':



        print('toggle turned ON')



        pc_ON()







# helper functions







def pc_ON():



    subprocess.run(['bash', '/home/mavr/Desktop/WOL.sh']) 



    print('turning the pc ON')



    











def is_connected():



    try:



        socket.create_connection(("1.1.1.1", 53))



        return True



    except OSError:



        pass



    return False











if __name__ == '__main__':



    client = MQTTClient(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)



    client.on_connect = connected                                   # set up the callbacks



    client.on_disconnect = disconnected



    client.on_message = message



                                           







    while not is_connected():                                       # make sure we have Internet (we may launch on reboot!)



        print(f'trying to get online...')



        time.sleep(2.0)



    print(f'we are online!')







    client.connect()                                                # connect to Adafruit server



    client.loop_background()



    print('Publishing a new message every 10 seconds (press Ctrl-C to quit)...')







    try:



        while True:



            value = random.randint(0, 100)



            print('Publishing {0} to pc feed.'.format(value))



            client.publish('pc', value)



            while not is_connected():                                       # make sure we have Internet (we may launch on reboot!)



                print(f'trying to get online...')



                time.sleep(2.0)



            print(f'we are online! | {datetime.now()}')



            time.sleep(600)



    except KeyboardInterrupt:



        print('disconnecting...')



        client.disconnect

()

